# How to make Java perform a listener task with a time delay?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, timer, listener

Consider a Java program in which a listener triggers a certain function. Suppose a user action activates the listener a few times in a row. My problem is: how do I make Java only execute the function only once in this triggering row and only if a certain amount of time has passed after the last activation of the listener?

I've tried to look up some information both on Google and on StackExchange, but I couldn't find any hints.

*(To provide some context: I'm trying to develop an Android app using the Google Maps API which includes drawing markers / marker clusters from a huge database of GPS points, wanting to only add the points in the current map view. If the user moves the map, the `OnCameraChangeListener` is activated quite a few times while the map still moves. However, since the database is quite huge and searching the GPS points for the given camera view might take some time, I don't want to trigger the function which adds the markers before the map view had been idle for, let's say, a second.)*

Comment: what do you have inside your OnCameraChangeListener? and take a look at Handler class which gives you a "postDelayed" method - do something after some time

Comment: You say Java but it seems you are more specifically asking about Android. Checkout Android's [Handler class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).

Comment: @NguyễnHoàiNam Nothing marker-related so far, only some code that draws a rectangle in the middle of the map, so I could see how OnCameraChangeListener works. Decided to write the code for marker clustering and drawing after figuring this problem out.

Comment: OnCameraChangeListener comes with a new CameraPosition object. You can store the last position and compare it with the latest position to control when you want to start drawing. And then you can use Handler to do so. Handler can help you queue some actions as well as cancel them on the flight. I can make a sample later, but give it a try.

Comment: read about [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)s

Answer (score 0):

You can simply hold on to those two values you described in your post:
 - Boolean isFunctionRunning
 - GregorianCalendar timeLastRun

Then if isFunctionRunning => false AND time since timeLastRun > 1 second, you start the function.